# Can't insert last_name record parallel to name record

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL and i'm using Microsoft SQL server 2012 ,I am trying to create a table that takes a record of id name and last name at first i create a table with two columns int and name then i insert record in them all goes perfectly then added a column last_name after that i tried to insert data in it the problem that i face is that i can't insert the record of last_name parallel to the record of id and name.

```
create table test (id int , name varchar(20));

insert into test(id,name)
values(1,'Abid'),(2,'Muhammad'),(3,'Raza'),(4,'Khan');

alter table test
add last_name varchar(20)
```

Comment: What did you try and what was the error? What does "parallel" mean? There's should be no problem with `insert into test(id,name,last_name)
values(1,'Abid','Whatever')`

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more details? Script you've posted will work perfectly, so what is *actual* problem?

Comment: what does "parallel to the record of id and name mean"? Does that mean you want to `update` a row? e.g. `update test set last_name = 'Muhammad' where id = 1`

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/6QYmQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to do. If you want to fill the last_name column to the already created rows, you need to use the UPDATE clause, and not insert :

```
UPDATE test
SET last_name = 'Abid's last name'
from test where id = 1
```

And repeat for all existing rows. You can also do :

```
create table test (id int , name varchar(20));
insert into test(id,name)
values(1,'Abid'),(2,'Muhammad'),(3,'Raza'),(4,'Khan');
alter table test
add last_name varchar(20) 
TRUNCATE TABLE test
insert into test(id,name,last_name)
values(1,'Abid','I'),(2,'Muhammad','Love'),(3,'Raza','SQL'),(4,'Khan','Server');
```

Happy coding !

Comment: Thanks a lot this pretty much solved my problem but i have query what if i  only want to update only last_name column and i don't want to write the values of id and name what should i do ?

Comment: In this case you'll do `INSERT INTO test(last_name) values ('Value1')`

Answer (score 0):

to modify a column in a row you must to UPDATE that row, in your case:

```
update test set last_name = 'last name' where id=1
```

remember the WHERE clause, if you dont put where, you go to update all last_name column for all rows.

hope this help!